# Connect Azure App Configuration to Azure WebJobs

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-app-configuration

I have multiple webjobs that should take their connection strings and application settings from Azure App Configuration.

I've tried following steps present in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-dotnet-app for app.config files in each webjob and for Web.config file of web application hosted with said webjobs as a App Service. In both cases configuration is not being read by webjobs. Is there any other way to pass data from Azure App Configuration to webjobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured because there was an empty web application used for hosting webjobs. Using executable web application in Azure App Service and setting connection string in it's Web.config file allows webjobs to connect to Azure App Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a HelloWorld WebJob project.

https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/tree/main/examples/DotNetCore/WebJobs

Comment: This an example for .Net Core project. My webjobs are written using .Net Framework.